# Function Problems and Local Variables

Tags: python

I am learning Python and am making a Q&A script.  I made one function for the questions.  That went rather well.  Now I am wanting an average function.  I want to avoid using globals if at all possible.  I know that my variables reset at the top... can someone please give me some pointers?  I know C/PHP/BASIC and want to grasp this langauge.  Below is my question function.

```
    def q(question, a, b, c, c_answer):
        total,tally=0,0
        print "",question
        print "   a.",str(a)
        print "   b.",str(b)
        print "   c.",str(c)
        u_answer = raw_input()
        if c_answer == "a" and u_answer == "a":
            print "Correct, the answer is A!"
            tally+=1
        elif c_answer == "b" and u_answer == "b":
            print "Correct, the answer is B!"
            tally+=1
        elif c_answer == "c" and u_answer == "c":
            print "Correct, the answer is C!"
            tally+=1
        else:
           print "I am sorry, but the correct answer is",c_answer
        print "\..n"
        total+=1
```

Comment: Which version r u using?

Comment: I mean something that takes an average. Its more of a statement:  (x/y)*100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just learning Python, I reformatted your code to be more pythonic.

```
def q(question, a, b, c, c_answer):
    total, tally = 0, 0
    print "", question
    print "   a. %s" % a
    print "   b. %s" % b
    print "   c. %s" % c
    u_answer = raw_input("your answer? ").strip()
    if c_answer == u_answer:
        print "Correct, the answer is %s!" % u_answer
        tally += 1
    else:
        print "I am sorry, but the correct answer is %s" % c_answer
    print "\n"
    total += 1
```

---

To actually answer your question:

There a couple ways to keep track of the total number of questions and correct answers without using global-level variables (actually module-level, but that's a different topic ;).

One is to pass in the current totals, have `q` recalculate based on the current question, and then pass them back out:

```
def q(question, a, b, c, c_answer, total, tally):
    print "", question
    print "   a. %s" % a
    print "   b. %s" % b
    print "   c. %s" % c
    u_answer = raw_input("your answer? ").strip()
    if c_answer == u_answer:
        print "Correct, the answer is %s!" % u_answer
        tally += 1
    else:
        print "I am sorry, but the correct answer is %s" % c_answer
    print "\n"
    total += 1
    return total, tally
```

Then in your main program you can say:

```
question_pool = (
    ('What is 2 + 2?', 2, 3, 4, 'c'),
    ('What is blue mixed with yellow?', 'green', 'orange', 'pink', 'a'),
    ('How far does light travel in one nanosecond?', '10 mm', '20 cm', '30 m', 'b'),
    )

total, tally = 0, 0
for packet in question_pool:
    question, a, b, c, answer = packet
    total, tally = q(question, a, b, c, answer, total, tally)

print "you answered %d correctly, for a score of %2.0f%%" % (tally, 100.0 * tally / total)
```

---

However, it would be better for `q` to just deal with questions, and not worry about keeping track of how many questions have been answered and how many questions have been asked.

So instead of accepting `total` and `tally`, recalculating, and returning `total` and `tally`, `q` will now just return `0` if the answer was wrong, `1` if it was correct:

```
def q(question, a, b, c, c_answer):
    print "", question
    print "   a. %s" % a
    print "   b. %s" % b
    print "   c. %s" % c
    u_answer = raw_input("your answer? ").strip()
    if c_answer == u_answer:
        print "Correct, the answer is %s!\n" % u_answer
        return 1
    print "I am sorry, but the correct answer is %s" % c_answer
    return 0
```

and the rest of the code looks like:

```
question_pool = (
    ('What is 2 + 2?', 2, 3, 4, 'c'),
    ('What is blue mixed with yellow?', 'green', 'orange', 'pink', 'a'),
    ('How far does light travel in one nanosecond?', '10 mm', '20 cm', '30 m', 'b'),
    )

total, tally = 0, 0
for packet in question_pool:
    question, a, b, c, answer = packet
    tally += q(question, a, b, c, answer)
    total += 1

print "you answered %d correctly, for a score of %.0f%%" % (tally, 100.0 * tally / total)
```

Comment: Doing this in C++ or BASIC didn't trouble me... Python is just that way I guess!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `total` from the `q` function. Instead, return 1 if the question is answered correctly, 0 otherwise:

```
def q(question, a, b, c, c_answer):
    ...
    return tally

num_correct = 0
for question in questions:
    num_correct += q(...)

average = float(num_correct) / len(questions)
```

If you don't want to use globals, simply organize your code in functions or class methods:

```
def ask_questions(questions):
    num_correct = 0
    for question in questions:
        num_correct += q(...)
    return num_correct

def report_average(num_correct, num_questions):
    average = float(num_correct) / num_questions
    print(average)

num_correct = ask_questions(questions)
report_average(num_correct, len(questions))
```

I think the basic idea is to use `return` to pass on the value(s) you need to the next function. If there are many pieces of data to keep track of, you could instead use class methods. By using a class, you can store values as instance attributes instead of using `return`:

```
class Exam(object):
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.num_correct = 0
        self.questions = ...

    def q(self, question, a, b, c, c_answer):
        ...
        if correct:
            self.num_correct += 1

    def ask_questions(self):
        for question in self.questions:
            self.q(question)

    def report_average(self):
        average = float(self.num_correct) / len(self.questions)
        print(average)
```

Comment: I know that the "..." means to insert my code, but I am confused as to where I print my question and check my answers from a pool of A,B, or C :-(

Comment: i find your code nice, but the class system is alien to me.  is it the same as c++

Comment: I think a very good explain of Python's class system (including a bit of comparison to C++) can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).